# Direct request to api responds properly but wso2 apim gateway doesn't

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am using wso2 apim 4.0.0. The issue that I am stuck with is when I send a direct request to an api (http://localhost:7743/api/products) itself it response back properly (i.e. It returns list of products).

```
[
   {
    "id":1,
    "name":"a"
   },
   {
    "id":2,
    "name":"b"
   }
]
```

But after publishing that api to apim, when I invoke that api (http://localhost:8243/api/products/v1) it keeps giving back not found which is incorrect.

```
{
    "statusCode": "404",
    "statusDescription": "Not found"
}
```

The response above is coming from my api itself not from gateway.
I unchecked response caching in publisher, restarted the server. But nothing has changed.

Any hint to overcome the issue is welcomed

Answer (score 0):

The gateway port is by default 8243. But you have tried to invoke it using port 9443. Change the port value and try it again. Also, ensure that the relevant API is deployed in the gateway. If not, even if the API is published it will not be available in the gateway and you won't be able to get the correct response.

Comment: yes, It is 8243, I mistyped it in the question. I checked the deployment and it is deployed. Is it possible that response caching is on even if I turned it off? Because when I created the api I checked response caching. After I came across the problem, I turned it off.

Comment: The response above is coming from my api(backend) itself not from gateway.